# My battery drop from 60% to 0%

Tags: battery

So i have this problem with my original battery. When my battery drop below 60%, its immediately change into 0% and died 30 second after.
And when im charge it, the battery fills from 0 to 50% and then changed into 100%.

I have tried some battery calibrate, factory reset and even buying new battery **twice** and still didnt work.
So is there anything i can do?

Comment: replace usb connector

Comment: I believe this is not an Android issue, but the issue is with your device - more specifically, the battery. Have you tried switching it?